# Upload file to FTP using FileZilla command line

Tags: sql-server, ftp, filezilla

I am working on a project where need to upload file to FTP using sql server. I know it can be done easily by SSIS or something like that but I have some barriers there. I was thinking of using Filezilla.But I don't know how to use it through command line. So that using xp_cmdShell.

Comment: what are the barriers to prevent you from using SSIS?

Answer (score 2):

Filezilla seems a bit of an odd route to go. You can use a dos batch file and one either the built-in ftp command-line executable or another open-source/free command-line alternative.

Bare in mind that xp_cmdShell requires elevated privileges and some system parameters to be modified which generally are not recommended.

As a workaround in the past I have created a sql job which used cmdExec and then just initiate using a stored  procedure.

EDIT: Added first result from google for batch file to upload to ftp

```
@echo off
echo user MyUserName> ftpcmd.dat
echo MyPassword>> ftpcmd.dat
echo bin>> ftpcmd.dat
echo put %1>> ftpcmd.dat
echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat
ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat SERVERNAME.COM
del ftpcmd.dat
```

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/how-to-automate-ftp-uploads-from-the-windows-command-line/